# simple window with an enter field

Tags: python, tkinter, window

i'm a new programmer and there are certainly several errors but this shouldn't be difficult to spot. I need to create a simple window with a field named "Concorrente 1:" and an entry field displayed by function named `lacopertina()`. I don't understand where is the error:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *
from tkinter import ttk

class schermoiniziale(tk.Frame):
    def lacopertina():
        print(gio1)

        #return (tot1)   
        
    def __init__(self):
        global gio1 
        #tot1=0
        #schermo1=Tk()
        
        self.gio1=tk.StringVar()
        lab1=ttk.Label(self, text="Concorrente 1:") 
        lab1.pack()      
        ent1=ttk.Entry(self, textvariable=self.gio1)
        ent1.pack()
        pulsante = ttk.Button(self, text="Inizio", textvariable=self.gio1, command=self.lacopertina)
        pulsante.pack()
        
def main():
    schermoiniziale().mainloop()
if __name__== "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: What is the error? You need to post the full traceback of the error.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to go through some tutorials on Python OOP.

I have modified your code as below with some comment:

```py
# avoid using wildcard import
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class schermoiniziale(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, **kw):
        # need to call __init__() of inherited class
        super().__init__(master, **kw)
        self.gio1 = tk.StringVar()
        lab1 = ttk.Label(self, text="Concorrente 1:")
        lab1.pack()
        ent1 = ttk.Entry(self, textvariable=self.gio1)
        ent1.pack()
        # removed textvariable=self.gio1 as I think you actually don't need it
        pulsante = ttk.Button(self, text="Inizio", command=self.lacopertina)
        pulsante.pack()

    def lacopertina(self):
        # use .get() to get the content of a StringVar
        print(self.gio1.get())

def main():
    # need to create the root window before creating other widget
    root = tk.Tk()
    # pass root window as the parent of the widget
    frame = schermoiniziale(root)
    frame.pack()
    # start the tkinter mainloop
    root.mainloop()

if __name__== "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: sorry, @acw1668 there is one more thing I can't do: what code should I add to switch to another window and display the content of self.gio1.get ()? Thank you so much

Comment: @JamesGarofalo Better raise another question for new issue.